vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq handle AMQPProtocolChannelException (NOT_FOUND - no queue in vhost)
I'm using vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq for laravel queue management and I have problen, when rabbitmq container just started, there are no queues declared, and my queue consumers instantry falling, is there any way to handle AMQPProtocolChannelException to declare queue manualy?
I tried to extend default RabbitMQQueue and RabbitMQStreamConnection classes to find entry point where exception can be catched, but no luck.
